# How to install Managed Package with Provider free Cache partitions in Professional Edition Org?

Tags: apex, managed-package, package-install, professional-edition, platform-cache

Issue : When trying to install a managed package in professional edition org, its failing with below error.

Error message:

> "This package can’t be installed. There are problems that prevent this
> package from being installed.
>
> 1. Platform Cache Partitions(cachePartitions/testcache.cachePartition) Missing feature
>
> Installing this package requires the following feature and its
> associated permissions: Platform Cache Partitions"

Note :

1. This managed package is security reviewed and has 3Mb of provider free platform cache cacpacity which is used in multiple places in the package
2. This package is installing without any issue in unlimited edition orgs.

Expectation : **To successfully install Managed Package with Provider free Cache partitions in Professional Edition Org**

So could you please suggest on this?

1. Is there any approach to install managed package in professional edition without removing platform cache from package itself?
2. Can we bypass platform cache functionality for professional edition so that the package will be installed?

For Reference:

I see similar point raised in below idea.

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZNAUA3/include-3mb-of-platform-cache-into-the-managed-package-for-professional-edition

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_limits.htm

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_features.htm) says it's not available for Professional Edition.   If you want to support PE, then you have to redesign your code to avoid using platform cache.